# How to listen to click events in pagination? QuerySelector returns null

Tags: angular, pagination, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to listen whenever pagination page changes.
I tried:

```
const button = document.querySelector(".ng-star-inserted");
button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    console.log('clicked');
});
```

Error: button gets value 'undefined'.
How can I listen to these page changes?

Code Snippet (Pagination):

```
<sui-pagination
      _ngcontent-d2c-frontend-c7=""
      class="pagination ui menu"
      _nghost-d2c-frontend-c11="">
      <!----><!----><a
        _ngcontent-d2c-frontend-c11=""
        class="item ng-star-inserted">
        <span _ngcontent-d2c-frontend-c11="">
          <i
            _ngcontent-d2c-frontend-c11=""
            class="angle left icon">
          </i></span></a>
      <!----><!----><a
        _ngcontent-d2c-frontend-c11=""
        class="item ng-star-inserted">

        1 </a>
      <a _ngcontent-d2c-frontend-c11="" class="item ng-star-inserted"> 2 </a>
      <a _ngcontent-d2c-frontend-c11="" class="item ng-star-inserted active">
        3 </a>
      <a _ngcontent-d2c-frontend-c11="" class="item ng-star-inserted"> 4 </a>
      <a _ngcontent-d2c-frontend-c11="" class="item ng-star-inserted"> 5 </a>
      <a _ngcontent-d2c-frontend-c11="" class="item ng-star-inserted"> 6 </a>
      <!----><!----><a
        _ngcontent-d2c-frontend-c11=""
        class="item ng-star-inserted">
        <span _ngcontent-d2c-frontend-c11="">
          <i
            _ngcontent-d2c-frontend-c11=""
            class="angle right icon">
          </i></span></a>
      <!----></sui-pagination
```

[image: Pagination SS]

Comment: Angular is built around binding HTML to your model and handling events. Use the (`click)="handleTheClick()` syntax to run your custom `handleTheClick()` function when the `click` event occurs on an element.

Comment: Class ```item ng-star-inserted``` is assigne to single element then why are you using both in querySelector?? You can use any itself know?? Either ```document.querySelector(".item");```  or ```document.querySelector(".ng-star-inserted");``` ??

Comment: @ManirajMurugan corrected that. Error still remains.

Comment: @AdnanAzmat, Look at this example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qy8sup, its working as expected..

Comment: @ManirajMurugan `const button = document.querySelector(".ng-star-inserted");` gives undefined

Comment: @AdnanAzmat, Did you open the console in the above stackblitz that i have provided?? I have given ```document.querySelector(".ng-star-inserted")``` only.. If possible provide a stackblitz and reproduce your issue..